# Wireframe only when rendered

Tags: rendering, wireframe

When I render my model I get this:
[image: Rendered Pic]

But I want it to look like a rendered version of this:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you may have selected *Wire* as the material type:

[image]

Try selecting *Surface* instead.